# Empty needle warning in system.log

Tags: magento-1.7, error, log

Been searching all over, does anyone have any tips on debugging this warning found in system.log? They appear to come in pairs ...

```
2013-07-18T06:40:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos() [<a href='function.strpos'>function.strpos</a>]: Empty needle  in /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 504
2013-07-18T06:40:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos() [<a href='function.strpos'>function.strpos</a>]: Empty needle  in /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 510
2013-07-18T06:45:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos() [<a href='function.strpos'>function.strpos</a>]: Empty needle  in /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 504
2013-07-18T06:45:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos() [<a href='function.strpos'>function.strpos</a>]: Empty needle  in /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 510
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, have a look at *lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php* on line 504 and 510.

Line 504:
`if (0 === strpos($requestUri, $baseUrl)) {`

Line 510:
`if (0 === strpos($requestUri, dirname($baseUrl))) {`

It appears that `$baseurl` is empty.

Since that variable can be set in number of ways, I'd suggest stepping through the method `public function setBaseUrl()` in that class using xdebug (or `Mage::log()` if you can't use a debugger for some reason) to figure out what is the problem.

Maybe you are dispatching Magento from a CLI script? Maybe it's part of some PHPUnit tests that don't mock the request object completely? Maybe some hack is messing with the `$_SERVER` superglobal?

No way to tell, you will have to work that out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs during the Cron Job.

See a temporary solution to this problem:

Edit file: `lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php`

Line 504: `if (0 === strpos($requestUri, $baseUrl)) {`

Replace with: `if (!empty($baseUrl) && 0 === strpos($requestUri, $baseUrl)) {`

Line 510: `if (0 === strpos($requestUri, dirname($baseUrl))) {`

Replace with: `if (!empty($baseUrl) && 0 === strpos($requestUri, dirname($baseUrl))) {`

**Note: It is strongly recommended that you do not alter the core files.**

Comment: Changing core files is a bad idea. Don't do it.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but as I said it's a quick fix. I should have said solution "temporary" in the comment.

Comment: If you edit your answer and add it I'm able to remove the -1 :-)

Comment: Could you share a fix without alter the core file?