# Can't get past checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

After patching new security update can't get past checkout, have reverted but still no luck.

It gets past payment info and shipment info its only when I click "Place Order" it does not load the next page, only thing that comes up in logs is:

<s>`ERR (3): Warning: strpos(): Empty needle  in /public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 508
ERR (3): Warning: strpos(): Empty needle  in /public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 514`</s>

Any way I can find the route of this problem?

Update:

Fixed the issue with the log clearing up but still can't place order.

Comment: It appears that $baseurl is empty. -->http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/empty-needle-warning-in-system-log

Comment: yeh that stops the error log clogging up does not fix my checkout issue :/

Comment: was working last week nothing has changed AFAIK apart from the update I have reverted